# magento 2 admin redirect loop after multistore configuration

Tags: magento2

Installed Magento 2 locally successfully locally on MAMP. Added a second store and edited .htaccess and index.php accordingly for a multistore environment.

I then edited the Base URL and Secure Base URL for store 1 to the new url and the admin now goes in a redirect loop.

So when I try to log in to the admin, example: **admin.com/admin_12345**, it tries to redirect to the store 1 url **store1.com/admin_12345** and ends up being a continuous loop until the browser fails.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Do not edit index.php. Leave it as it is and the problem will be solved. Just change the .htaccess

Comment: Its not the store that has the redirect issue, its the admin. the admin now loads but under the store url but still does not function properly.